# How to use gmail account for ssrs email subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, iis-7, ssrs-2008

I have a report using **SSRS 2008 R2**, I want to subscribe to this report using the "email" option. I have configured the settings in the reporting services manager to use server as "smtp.gmail.com" and sender address as my gmail ID.

I also tried using the SMTP virtual server and relay it using smart host as "smtp.gmail.com". But I get the following error while sending email :

> Failure sending mail: The transport failed to connect to the server.

I am using **IIS 7** and **Windows Server 2008**. Following is the snippet of my `rsreportserver.config` file:

```
<SMTPServer>smtp.gmail.com</SMTPServer>
<SMTPServerPort>587
</SMTPServerPort>
<SMTPAccountName>
</SMTPAccountName>
<SMTPConnectionTimeout>
</SMTPConnectionTimeout>
<SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
</SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
<SMTPUseSSL>True
</SMTPUseSSL>
<SendUsing>2</SendUsing>
<SMTPAuthenticate></SMTPAuthenticate>
<From>myid@gmail.com</From>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have enabled SMTP in your Gmail settings, & where is your password in the code ? Paste your complete config file.

Comment: yes I have enabled in my gmail account settings. Regarding the password in config file, no node exists to carry the password information, How should I introduce that ? I set my credentials in the virtual server though and changed the SMTPServer node value to the virtual server address .. but the error persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I have read, it sounds like you might have to setup a local SMTP relay server that you send the email through, b/c SSRS requires that "The Report Server service must have Send As permissions on the SMTP server" and does not appear to give any options for entering a password.  I am assuming the SSRS subscription email setup only works using Windows authentication since it uses the SSRS Service, but the configuration documentation is vague. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345234(v=sql.105).aspx )

Here is a link that shows how to setup the SMTP relay server http://www.vsysad.com/2012/04/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Here are the steps you'll need to do differently.

- Item 19, choose Basic Authentication, enter your gmail account info, and make sure TLS encryption is checked.
- Item 21, enter **your** server name as the Fully-qualiified domain name.  Enter "smtp.google.com" as the "Smart host".

Then specify the SMTP server you just created above in your SSRS SMTP configuration.

You probably also need to enable POP3 on your gmail account if you have not already. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13273?cbid=wl8yzeug2lob&src=cb&lev=topic

Comment: Thanks for all these resources, they helped me a lot. Apart from this, for using gmail accounts, we need to configure our gmail account to be made accessible from other devices and applications. For this, log into gmail account and go to this link: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha . And you are good to go :) (resource: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/django-gmail-smtpauthenticationerror)

Answer (score 6):

I was having a problems getting SSRS 2017 to connect.  I tried a dozen different suggestions and ended up with the following.  I didn't need to setup the SMTP relay or SMTP service on the windows server.

Open **Reporting Services Configuration Manager**.  Go to **E-mail Settings** >>>

- Sender Address: [user]@gmail.com (or your G-Suite domain)
- Current Delivery Method: Use SMTP server
- SMTP Server: smtp.gmail.com
- Authentication= "Username and password (basic)"
- Username: [user]@gmail.com (or your G-Suite domain)
- Password
- Confirm Password
- Use Secure Connection: Checked

Now go to the **rsreportserver.config** file.  Mine was located at
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config

Find the **`<SMTPServerPort>`** and set to **587**

**Save** rsreportserver.config

**You'll also need to enable "Less secure app access" in the Security section of your Google Account settings otherwise will throw authentication errors.**

Comment: I have been using SSRS since SQL 2005, and this is the *first* time I've ever been able to use it purely through its own configuration with authenticated SMTP to Gmail (SSRS 2017) - this response was the only documented case I've seen so far and was a huge help.  Finally I can remove the SMTP relay server I had installed several OS / SQL versions ago on this server

Comment: @user2044384 glad it worked for you and prevented one more SMTP relay in this world.

Answer (score 4):

Having struggled with this for the past few hours I thought it might be valuable to share another method for anyone else still unable to configure an SSRS instance to send subscription emails via gmail using their smtp relay service.

For this example, my company uses Gmail Servers to host our own domain and I assume that you have access to the Admin Console on Google Apps.

**Step 1 - Configure Gmail**

- Log into Google Apps with an Administrator Account
- Go into the admin console
- Select Apps > Gmail > Advanced Settings
- Find SMTP Relay Service
- Add New
- 1. Allowed Senders - Set to "Only Addresses In My Domains"
- 2. Authentication - Set to "Only Accept Mail From Specified IP"
- 3. Add the Public IP Range of the Server SSRS is running on
- 4. Leave TLS Encryption Unchecked
- 5. Leave SMTP Authentication Unchecked
- 6. Save

You should then have settings that look like this:

- Allowed senders: Only addresses in my domains
- Only accept mail from the specified IP addresses: Yes
- Allowed IP addresses: (Your Description)
- Require SMTP Authentication: No
- Require TLS encryption: No

**Step 2 - Configure SSRS**

- Go to SSRS Configuration Manager > Email Settings
- Enter Sender address as email@yourgmaildomain.co.uk
- Use SMTP Server
- SMTP Server = "smtp-relay.gmail.com"

Following these steps will allow you to send emails using SSRS subscriptions without needing to set up your own relay server. Hope this helps some other poor sole from spending hours trying to figure it out!

REF:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?vid=1-635782669150538047-3380580329