# Scheduling and Delivery Processor cannot connect to the SMTP server smtp.gmail.com that is used for e-mail delivery

Tags: reporting-services

Getting error in Data Driven subscription Scheduling and Delivery Processor cannot connect to the SMTP server smtp.gmail.com that is used for e-mail delivery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use gmail account for ssrs email subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479550/how-to-use-gmail-account-for-ssrs-email-subscription)

Comment: Hi Dale Thanks for your information.Solved Issue.